# Could not able to see anything on iOS simulator other than iPhone 4S

Tags: ios, xcode6, simulator

I have come across a strange issue that when I run my app on the iOS simulator I could see the content only on iPhone 4S simulator and nothing comes up on any other simulators. I have this issue of the table view with custom cell. This custom cell got 5 UILabels and one UIImageView and all added programmatically. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Below are the screen shots. one with two rows on the table view is from iPhone 4S simulator and one with blank table view is from iPhone 5S simulator for the same app.

[image: Screen Shot of iPhone 4S Simulator]
[image: Screen Shot of iPhone 5S Simulator]

and here is my code in the Table View Controller..........

```
import UIKit

import CoreData

class projectListTableViewController: UITableViewController,  NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {


var projectList = []


var fetchResultController : NSFetchedResultsController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.title = "Projects"

    fetchfromCoreData()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

 override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


    return projectList.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("projectCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as projectDetailCell

    let projectProperty : AnyObject = projectList[indexPath.row]



    cell.projectid.text = (projectProperty.valueForKey("projectID") as String)
    cell.projectname.text = (projectProperty.valueForKey("projectName") as String)
    cell.customer.text = (projectProperty.valueForKey("customerName") as String)

    var numberofTanks : NSNumber = projectProperty.valueForKey("numberOfTanks") as NSNumber

    cell.tanks.text = numberofTanks.stringValue

    cell.backgroundView = drawcellBackground()



    return cell

}


//.........implementing delete option.......................

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {

    return true

}



 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {



    var itemToDelete = self.fetchResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as NSManagedObject

    var delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

    var managedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext

    managedObjectContext?.deleteObject(itemToDelete)


    var e : NSError?



    if managedObjectContext?.save(&e) != true {

        println("delete error: \(e!.localizedDescription)")
    }

   fetchfromCoreData()



}


//...............fix the height...................................//

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 60
}






  //................pass the data to the detail view.................//

 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "detailProject") {



        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {

            let navController = segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController
            let destinationView = navController.topViewController as projectDetailTableViewController
            let projectProperty : AnyObject = projectList[indexPath.row]

            destinationView.titleName = (projectProperty.valueForKey("projectID") as String)
            destinationView.numberofTanks = projectProperty.valueForKey("numberOfTanks") as NSNumber
        }


    }

}




//..........feting data from the persistant Store..................................//

func fetchfromCoreData() {


    var fetchrequest = NSFetchRequest (entityName: "Projects")
    var sortOrder = NSSortDescriptor(key: "projectID", ascending: true)
    fetchrequest.sortDescriptors = [sortOrder]

    if let dataContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext {

        fetchResultController = NSFetchedResultsController (fetchRequest: fetchrequest, managedObjectContext: dataContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

        fetchResultController.delegate = self

        var e : NSError?

        var result = fetchResultController.performFetch(&e)

        self.projectList = fetchResultController.fetchedObjects!

        if result != true {
            println(e?.localizedDescription)
        }

    }


    self.tableView.reloadData()


}
```

}

and this is UITableViewCell

```
import UIKit

class projectDetailCell: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet var projectid : UILabel!
@IBOutlet var projectname : UILabel!
@IBOutlet var logo : UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var customer : UILabel!
@IBOutlet var numberoftanks : UILabel!
@IBOutlet var tanks : UILabel!

var screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds





override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    var screenWidth = screenSize.width

    self.projectid = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(2, 0, screenWidth*1/4-2, 29.5))
    self.projectname = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(screenWidth*1/4, 0, screenWidth*3/4-30, 29.5))
    self.logo = UIImageView (frame: CGRectMake(screenWidth-30, 20, 20, 20))
    self.customer = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(5, 30.5, screenWidth*1/2, 29.5))
    self.numberoftanks = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(screenWidth*1/2, 30.5, 0.8*(screenWidth/2-50), 29.5))
    self.tanks = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(screenWidth*1/2 + 0.8*(screenWidth/2-50), 30.5, 29.5, 29.5))

    //configure the above boxes

    projectid.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20)
    projectid.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.682, blue: 0.937, alpha: 0.5)
    projectid.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    projectid.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    projectid.clipsToBounds = true
    self.addSubview(projectid)

    projectname.numberOfLines = 0
    projectname.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    projectname.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14)
    projectname.textColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    self.addSubview(projectname)

    customer.numberOfLines = 0
    customer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    customer.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    customer.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(UIFont.smallSystemFontSize())
    customer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0)
    customer.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    customer.clipsToBounds = true
    self.addSubview(customer)

    numberoftanks.numberOfLines = 0
    numberoftanks.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    numberoftanks.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(UIFont.smallSystemFontSize())
    numberoftanks.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    numberoftanks.text = NSLocalizedString("Number of Tanks:",  comment: "")
    numberoftanks.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0)
    numberoftanks.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    numberoftanks.clipsToBounds = true
    self.addSubview(numberoftanks)

    tanks.numberOfLines = 0
    tanks.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    tanks.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(UIFont.smallSystemFontSize())
    tanks.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.3)
    tanks.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    tanks.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    tanks.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    tanks.clipsToBounds = true
    self.addSubview(tanks)

    logo.image = UIImage(named: "document")
    self.addSubview(logo)



}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}



}
```

Comment: Where is your dataset coming from?

Comment: You need to post some code - you'd have to by partially psychic to answer this as it stands.

Comment: before trying other method reset content and setting might help

Comment: I have posted the complete code I have in the UITableView and UITableViewCell.